# Asp.Net MVC Partial View Update Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an asp.net mvc application. I am trying to update a partial view that is inside main view with ajax post. Here is my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "Interface/GetErrors?servers=" + serverNames,
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#errorListDiv').html(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured");
            }
        });
```

Actually this ajax post gets partial view successfully. But my problem is; after partial view loads, some css classes, html attributes etc. loads incomplete. Because some parts of partial views are arranged and created with javascript functions. Because of this javascript libraries render in main view or viewstart and this libraries will not be rendered with ajax post, my partial view loads incomplete. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do your js functions look like?  It could be your js that is giving the issues, anything on the console?

Comment: `1)` never use `async: false`. Ever. Period. `2)` any queries, see item `1)`!

Comment: One way: You need to have all JS available from the parent page, i.e. any plugins used on the child page, and re-run any methods inside the `success` callback.

Comment: Another way: It is possible (but messy) to extract the JavaScript from the raw incoming page text and get it to execute. I used a RegEx to match the script blocks myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned a few methods in my comments. Here is the one you may need:

Extract any `<script>` blocks from the raw HTML and cause them to execute. I believe `html()` strips out `script` blocks.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Interface/GetErrors?servers=" + serverNames,
    type: "Post",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (result) {
        $('#errorListDiv').html(result);
        var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
        var scripts = "";
        var match;
        while (match = re.exec(result)) {
            if (match[1] != "") {
                scripts += match[0];
            }
        }
        // cause the scripts to execute - add them to the panel loaded
        $('#errorListDiv').append(scripts);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error occured");
    }
});
```

You will need to ensure your partial views only contains blocks of script code and not script file references or you may double-up on your includes.

*There may well be a better way to do this, but this worked for me, so I am happy to hear comments.*

*Note: Please do not ever use `async: false`. It causes any numebr of additional problems for little benefit. Just use the async callbacks provided (which you are anyway).